# Using a for loop within innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, for-loop, innerhtml

I want to add a box with individual boxes inside it with every age when the function is run. I tried doing it by splitting the innerHTML and using the for loop on just the agebox section so it will loop and create a new age box each time and not create a whole outerbox as well everytime like if you try loop the entire thing. I thought this would work but now it creates an age box for each loop but its placed outside the outer box and i cant figure out how to get it to loop within the outer box. If i remove the loop and just create one innerHTML then the age boxes i made manually are inside the outer box so im assuming theres a problem with the actual splitting up of the innerHTML. Thanks in advance!!

```
function Age(gender){
        if (gender!==undefined){
            el1 = document.getElementById('userdata');
            el1.innerHTML += gender +"<br>";    
        }
        el1 = document.getElementById('farespage');
        el1.innerHTML += "<div id=\"outerbox\">";
        for(var i=13; i<=18; i++){
            el1.innerHTML +="<div class=\"agebox\" onclick=\"Relationship('"+i+"')\">"+i+"</div>";
        }
        el1.innerHTML += "</div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goback('Gender')\">back</button>";
    }
```

Comment: Just don't treat the DOM as though it's a string of HTML, and you'll do much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the output content as a string and then append it to the DOM. Otherwise, the div will be auto-closed.

```
el1 = document.getElementById('farespage');

output = "<div id=\"outerbox\">"; //initialize output string

//build output string
for(var i=13; i<=18; i++){
    output +="<div class=\"agebox\" onclick=\"Relationship('"+i+"')\">"+i+"</div>";
}

output += "</div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goback('Gender')\">back</button>";

el1.innerHTML = output; //output to DOM
```

[View Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k9r4k1c/1/)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense but when i try it then nothing happens at all now

Comment: It works in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k9r4k1c/1/), so there must be something else going wrong in your code.

Comment: Ah i changed the id and class names when i wrote this so it would be easier to explain and i just copy pasted your code haha but now its working perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice solution. Works fine.

Comment: I needed to generate 1 to 5 input fields using a range input to generate the numeric value and this example give me the answer I needed to make it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
el1.innerHTML += "<div id=\"outerbox\">";
```

is actually producing

```
<div id="outerbox"></div>
```

because most browsers will auto-close the HTML tags.

You should write all your HTML into a string buffer then append it with one big call; for example:

```
function Age(gender){
    if (gender!==undefined){
        el1 = document.getElementById('userdata');
        el1.innerHTML += gender +"<br>";    
    }

    el1 = document.getElementById('farespage');
    // Magic begins here
    var yourHTML = "";
    yourHTML += "<div id=\"outerbox\">";
    for(var i=13; i<=18; i++){
        yourHTML +="<div class=\"agebox\" onclick=\"Relationship('"+i+"')\">"+i+"</div>";
    }
    yourHTML += "</div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goback('Gender')\">back</button>";

    el1.innerHTML += yourHTML;
}
```

This has the added benefit of only touching the DOM once and not 7 times (which is generally a good thing).